# Android studio: upload image to web API

Tags: java, android, asp.net-web-api, image-uploading

I need to make app that take photo, place photo in image view and when I click button to upload to web API service.

My problem is when I try upload photo, I have next error in code.

```
public void makeHTTPCall() {

    prgDialog.setMessage("Invoking php");
    StringEntity se = null;

    try{
        se = new StringEntity(params.toString());
        se.setContentType("application/json");
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

    AsyncHttpClient image = new AsyncHttpClient();

    image.post(uploadURL, se, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()
```

[image]

This is my error. And my imports

```
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
```

As u can i see, I have imported .RequestParams and .StringEntity

And when I run app I have this:

[image]

Any idea what to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using AsyncHttpClient, and the lib is support file upload with easy way.

```
image.post(uploadURL, se, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()
```

'se' is not StringEntity as like log result 'StringEntity cannot be converted to RequestParams.

```
image.post(targetUrl, params, Responsehandler(){});
```

You should do like this.

This is a sample code for file upload with AsyncHttpClient:

```
RequestParam params = new RequestParams();
params.put("key1", "value1");
params.put("key2", "value2");

File imgFile = new File(filePath);
try {
      params.put("file",imgFile);
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {}

AsyncHttpClient image = new AsyncHttpClient();
image.post(uploadURL, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){});
```

Comment: When i try this sample, I get the status code 415: Unsupported Media Type.